# Replace a series of numbers with their consecutive differences, as they are entered

Tags: function, math, google-sheets, difference

I want to calculate the difference for each row from D(ay)1 to D(ay)2, from D2 to D3 and so on, but how? And I want the difference to be shown like "+30" in the same cell as I enter the value.

**EDIT:** I'm thinking it might be possible to present the difference by using custom cell format?

[image: Table]

Comment: Store numbers, and record the units in the column header

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do with custom number format, although it will help to have + in front of positive numbers (use the format `+#;#` for this).

The replacement of values with differences would have to be done with an [Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) such as the one below. It checks that the edit was made to a cell in row > 1 and column > 8, and calculates the change of values. For example, if column H has 315 and you enter 345 in column I, the result will be +30 in column I. Then, if you place 310 in column J, it will be replaced by -35.

The number 8 used in the script refers to column H, which is where the base values are entered.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (row > 1 && col > 8 && typeof e.value != 'object') {
    var values = sheet.getRange(row, 8, 1, col-8).getValues()[0];
    var s = values[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
      s += values[i];
    }
    e.range.setValue(e.value - s);
  }
}
```